# background image for tabBar

Tags: ios, swift

I use [PTCardTabBar](https://github.com/marcmora/PTCardTabBar) like `tabBar` in my app. But I need to use an image as a background for my `tabBar`. But so that I don't try to do it, I can't use images in as a background `PTCardTabBar`. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]find PTCardTabBarController.swift file from pod installed -> replace the setupTabBar function and add @available(iOS 13.0, *).

```
   import UIKit
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    open class PTCardTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
        fileprivate func setupTabBar(){
                customTabBar.delegate = self
                self.view.addSubview(customTabBar)
                
                customTabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallBottomView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                customTabBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                customTabBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: horizontleSpacing).isActive = true
                customTabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tabBarHeight).isActive = true
                
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(customTabBar)
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(smallBottomView)
                
                customTabBar.tintColor = tintColor
                customTabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage (named: "your image")!)
            }
    }
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension PTCardTabBarController: CardTabBarDelegate {
    func cardTabBar(_ sender: PTCardTabBar, didSelectItemAt index: Int) {
        self.selectedIndex = index
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to change tabBar background (change white background on custom image). Not tabBarItems

Comment: Any thoughts on how to change the `tabBar` background?

Comment: background image or colour ?

Comment: background image

Comment: plz check the updated code and just copy and replace the function to the PTCardTabBarController.swift file, hope it will work.

Comment: Have you tried running it yourself? If this works for you, then you can share your project. The problem is that I have tried to sole the problem with using `patternImage`. But it does not work for me. And if I use your code, then nothing happens either. Maybe my image is just not active for my pods files? This should work, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @User can you show your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: plz add  '@available(iOS 13.0, *)'  in ViewController.swift, PTTabBarViewController and PTCardTabBarController like check above updated code.